# Регулярные выражения в MySQL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql

Такой вопрос, насколько эффективно использование регулярок в запросах к БД
Например, у меня есть база, в которой 2000 статей. Необходимо сделать выборку статей, в тексте которых есть фраза, удовлетворяющая некой регулярке. Сделать это можно:

1. Считать все статьи, а дальше,
           средствами php например, отобрать
           необходимые
2. Использовать
           регулярку в запросе к БД (то есть,
           использование LIKE, RLIKE и тд)

Собственно, как лучше поступать и в каких случаях?

Answer (score 4):

Лучше на уровне БД выполнять всё что можно, особенно отсеивание и выборку данных.
Причины на это очень простые:

1. У MySQL данные организованы специально для поиска, т.е. однако в случае с регулярками это не столь существенно
2. MySQL читает данные сразу из памяти.
3. PHP работает заметно медленнее MySQL, написанного на С++
4. Передача данных из MySQL в PHP происходит через сетевые интерфейсы, затем обрабатывается адаптером PHP чтобы из формата MySQL преобразовать в PHP формат.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не рекомендовал использовать регулярки в MySQL при большом объеме данных, они будут сильно нагружать сервер и тормозить, лучше продумать полнотекстовый поиск по словам (MATCH AGAINST) или использовать LIKE с индексом, но как было сказано выше, ни в коем случае, не делать фильтр средствами PHP.